# How do you debug "value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property" errors?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding

I'm getting the following in the program output when I run my application.  When I search my application I can not find any time named "btnOpen."

I know these binding errors is because some bound-property is returning null to the tooltip.name.  But, is this in my program, a referenced library, or something else?  How do I track these down?  I don't know and can't find btnOpen or btnPrint. My print buttons don't even use tooltips.

> System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='' BindingExpression:Path=ToolTip; DataItem='Button' (Name='btnOpen'); target element is 'Button' (Name='btnOpen'); target property is 'Name' (type 'String')
>
> System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='' BindingExpression:Path=ToolTip; DataItem='Button' (Name='btnPrint'); target element is 'Button' (Name='btnPrint'); target property is 'Name' (type 'String')

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Have you tried to search/find in files for these names "btnOpen". ctrl+alt+f to open search window... I put this as answer as well...

Comment: share the binding xaml snippet ?

Comment: It turned out to be an error in xaml from a third party dll.  It's something I can't fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use Hungarian notation when naming your controls, that might be the first clue that `btnOpen` is not part of your project. Are you using any third-party controls? If so, open up the libraries in Reflector and see if you can find any references to `btnOpen`. That's where I would go.

Answer (score 0):

The elements are named, so search your solution for `btnOpen` and `btnPrint`, as those are the elements with the bindings.